# Pyspark - GroupBy and Count combined with a WHERE

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, apache-spark, group-by, pyspark

Say I have a list of magazine subscriptions, like so:

```
subscription_id    user_id       created_at
 12384               1           2018-08-10
 83294               1           2018-06-03
 98234               1           2018-04-08
 24903               2           2018-05-08
 32843               2           2018-03-06
 09283               2           2018-04-07
```

Now I want to add a column that states how many previous subscriptions a user had, before this current subscription. For example, if this is the user's first subscription, the new column's value should be 0. If they had one subscription starting before this subscription, the new column's value should be 1. Here is the full desired output:

```
subscription_id    user_id       created_at        users_previous_subs
 12384               1           2018-08-10                  2
 83294               1           2018-06-03                  1
 98234               1           2018-04-08                  0
 24903               2           2018-05-08                  2
 32843               2           2018-04-06                  1
 09283               2           2018-03-07                  0
```

How can I accomplish this, preferably in PySpark, therefore not using `shift`

Let me know if this is not clear. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try windowing functions with `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This boils down to `row_number` calculation.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
#Define a window
w = Window.partitionBy(df.user_id).orderBy(df.created_at)
#Add an extra column with rownumber
df.withColumn('prev_subs',func.row_number().over(w)-1)
df.show()
```

If there can be ties, (i.e. more than 1 row with a given date for a user), use `dense_rank`.

```
df.withColumn('prev_subs',func.dense_rank().over(w)-1)
```